Are LITTLE_ENDIAN, BIG_ENDIAN and BYTE_ORDER macros supposed to be polluting my global namespace with GCC?
I had a class like this:
class ByteOrder
{public:

    enum class ByteOrderEnum : unsigned char { BIG_ENDIAN = 0, LITTLE_ENDIAN = 1 };
//^^^ error: expected identifier before numeric constant

    static inline ByteOrderEnum this_system_byte_order = []() {
            
        return ByteOrderEnum::BIG_ENDIAN; // WHATEVER FOR NOW (JUST EXAMPLE)
    }();
}

This error comes up on GCC, but not Visual Studio. And to be honest I think I compiled this also on Clang and it worked fine. So it took me ages to figure out that in my usr/include there is a file named endian.h that's somehow being included in my source. I'm wondering if this is normal, and what it's part of, and if I have to rename my enums.
Here is the offending code in "endian.h":
/* Get the definitions of __*_ENDIAN, __BYTE_ORDER, and __FLOAT_WORD_ORDER.  */
#include <bits/endian.h>
#ifdef __USE_MISC
# define LITTLE_ENDIAN  __LITTLE_ENDIAN
# define BIG_ENDIAN __BIG_ENDIAN
# define PDP_ENDIAN __PDP_ENDIAN
# define BYTE_ORDER __BYTE_ORDER
#endif


do you include endian.h ? Your example should not have an error because nothing is being included. Or are you saying that its caused by a header that is included by gcc by default?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai No my example isn't my actual code, there are hundreds of files, and somewhere something is including usr/include/endian.h It's not me. But maybe a standard library header?

here is a repo. including string, vector and iostream is sufficient to get the error https://godbolt.org/z/zcxeh97rP. I would call it a bug. Those arent reserved identifiers and I doubt either of those 3 is allowed to introduce those macros

further experimenting shows that string and iostream introduce the name :/

macros do not respect any namespaces. Macros are  preprocessor feature and preprocesor is oblivious of language syntax.

Damn stupid thing just took too much time out of my life. Or stupid me for using LITTLE_ENDIAN and BIG_ENDIAN, I'm using two underscores now.

@Zebrafish Using two underscores is the wrong thing to do. Names with two consecutive underscores are reserved for the compiler and should not be defined by user code. That's what gcc should be doing, but I guess they can't for some kind of backward compatibility reasons.

There is a rule of thumb to use ALL_UPPERCASE only for macros. That kind of makes it a separate namespace. (Once upon a time all constants in C were #defines, so uppercase. That doesn't mean that constants are supposed to be uppercase, only the macros).

@BoP - +1 I find this write up on the topic, by Jonathan Wakely, to be compelling.

These things just happen. Not too long ago, I changed a template <typename CALLBACK> ... to template <typename FUNC>..., because VisualC++ appears to have a "CALLBACK" macro... just deal with it. You could also #undef the macro to free up the identifier, but that's only feasible if you do it in a sourcefile (not a header) so you can do it AFTER all system headers that might have used it have been read.

@john Umm, two leading underscores, right? I decided to make it ByteOrderEnum::LITTLE__ENDIAN. That should be alright?

@Zebrafish No two consecutive underscores anywhere in the identifier.

@john Ohhh really? How about three?

@Zebrafish I'm not sure if you are joking. Full rules here, sixth bullet point in the section 'In declarations'.

If you have three consecutive underscores in your identifier, does any subsequences of those consist of two consecutive underscores?

No, if the environment was fully standard-conforming, then neither BIG_ENDIAN nor LITTLE_ENDIAN should be used by the standard library or compiler and you should be free to use these identifiers as you see fit.
However, glibc, the library that you are using to provide the C standard library functionality, also includes a lot of optional functionality that is not included in the standard library and that includes names such as BIG_ENDIAN or LITTLE_ENDIAN (although I couldn't actually find them documented in the glibc man pages).
Normally, when you request the compiler to act standard-conforming with e.g. the option -std=c99, then glibc will default to not include such optional functionality and a user must request their inclusion specifically by defining one of the feature test macros.
However, unfortunately this doesn't work for GCC when compiling C++ on Linux. In this constellation GCC always pre-defines the _GNU_SOURCE feature macro, telling glibc to include GNU-specific functionality that also includes definitions of BIG_ENDIAN and LITTLE_ENDIAN.
This is done because libstdc++, the C++ standard library implementation used with the GCC compiler, doesn't currently work without the GNU extensions. See Why is _GNU_SOURCE defined by default and how to turn it off? for a detailed explanation and authoritative links.

So, to get it to compile on the GCC/glibc/Linux combination, at least if you are going to include any standard library header, you need to use a different identifier. Note that you generally are not allowed to use identifiers for your own purposes that start with an underscore followed by upper-case letter or that contain (anywhere) a double underscore.

Would adding #undef BIG_ENDIAN and #undef LITTLE_ENDIAN after the includes also work?

@ChristianHalaszovich Maybe, but then it might be that headers included later rely on them being defined. Although I don't expect it.
